# Exception on instance weights when Using SVM and Weka from my own JAVA Code

Tags: svm, weka, libsvm

I'm writing my own JAVA code using WEKA and LibSVM.
I'm using weka 3.8.3, libsvm-3.23 and libsvm-1.0.6

I get the following error when the method buildClassifier of LibSVM is executed (SVMMy extends LibSVM)

```
SEVERE: null
weka.core.WekaException: mycode.SVMMy: Some instance weights are not equal to 1 and scheme does not implement the WeightedInstancesHandler interface!
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1307)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1138)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1468)
    at weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM.buildClassifier(LibSVM.java:1652)
```

Can you explain me what is the problem?
The same object Instances is previously correctly classified by a Random Forest.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

LibSVM cannot handle instance weights, but J48 can. See http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/core/WeightedInstancesHandler.html for classifiers that can handle instance weights.